# Return Cached response when user is offline using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, offline-caching

I am trying to achieve an offline feature for my web app where $http.get request return cached response/ fetch from local storage if possible when user is offline.

In my service, I have

```
service.getRequest = function(){
                        if(!navigator.onLine){
                        //return cached response or localStorage[JSON.parse(url)]
                     }
                    else {
                         var deferred = $q.defer();
                         $http.get(url, {cache : true})
                              .success(function(data) {
                                   localStorage[url] = JSON.stringify(data);  
                                   deferred.resolve(data);
                              })
                              .error(function() {
                                 deferred.reject('Unable to get request');
                              });
                         return deferred.promise;
                    }
                  }
```

Any help?

Comment: Does the error function get executed? Wouldn't you read from your localStorage to get the data?  Aside from this, you have to make sure the web app runs even if the user is offline. I assume you've taken care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Caching is a built in feature for the $http service.  You do not need to implement your own solution.  See the documentation's caching section:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Thanks @Austin, I have added cache:true to my request. But how do i enforce http.get to return the cached response if network is not available?

Answer (score 0):

If you want API calls to be handled whilst offline even if the user hasn't made that exact call yet in this browser session then the built-in angualr caching won't be enough.

You can add an [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) to change how `$http` calls are handled. In here you can then check if the user is offline and handle it differently.